# Mobx - when to use useLocalStore hook with react-mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I don't get why `useLocalStore` hook exist. I am declaring stores *outside* of the React component body using the `observable` method imported from `mobx` lib.

Then, every component that uses the store in any way is wrapped into `observer` HOC from `mobx-react`.

Everything works perfectly fine, but I'm not sure whether I'm not doing something wrong because `useLocalStore` hook is used all over the documentation and I'm not using it.

Example with store being declared outside of the react component:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

const person = observable({ name: 'John' })

const Person = observer(function Person() {
  return (
    <div>
      {person.name}
      <button onClick={() => (person.name = 'Mike')}>No! I am Mike</button>
    </div>
  )
})
```

Why would I use `useLocalStore` hook?

Comment: Try to create two <Person> components and you'll see the problem, they will share their person, unlike the answer below

Comment: Ah got it, that makes sense, because they will share the person observable. For global stuff like authentication I think it's fine to declare "stores" outside of the components - will be careful about that tho :) Thank you for mobx - it's great, I've no idea why I used redux for so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates a local observable that will be **stable between renderings**.

You can use if with functional components. In the example, you can see that the component doesn't depend on any `react context` or `external store`, but it's still using `mobx` and it's completely self-contained.

```
import { useObserver, useLocalStore } from 'mobx-react'
function Person() {
  const person = useLocalStore(() => ({ name: 'John' }))
  return useObserver(() => (
    <div>
      {person.name}
      <button onClick={() => (person.name = 'Mike')}>No! I am Mike</button>
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just added an example with store being declared outside of the component. Is that wrong and not "stable between rerenders"?

Comment: Everything that is outside the component is stable because it is not redeclared every time the function component runs/renders. 
That is also the main principle behind `React.createContenxt`

Answer (score 0):

useLocalStore has been deprecated in favor of useLocalObservable, see [here.](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite#uselocalstoret-sinitializer---t-source-s-t-deprecated)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer